# Can a KD tree be used as a decision tree through nearest neighbor queries?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

If I were to construct a KD tree representing a sufficiently dense space, could it be used as a decision tree by querying it for the nearest neighbor to the point to classify?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  The scheme you are thinking of is called the [nearest-neighbors classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).  Read the link for more details.  In many settings it turns out to be a quite effective classification algorithm.